# How do I execute multiple threads with the same function but different parameter concurrently

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
 for (long key = 0; key < 5; key++)
{
var processingThread = new Thread(() => Setup(key));
processingThread.Start();
}
```

I want to execute the `Setup(key)` function with each key value but at the same time on multiple windows..

Comment: What happens? You've been bitten by the [closing over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)?

Comment: take a look at [ParameterizedThreadStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Being not %100 sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, I think Parallel.For can be used in this case.See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405938/save-time-with-parallel-for-loop).

Comment: thanks Yoav.. But in my case i want to execute the setup() function with key=1 in one window, then setup() function with key=2 in second window, and so on..

Comment: for (long key = 0; key < 5; key++)
{
var processingThread = new Thread(() => Setup(key));
processingThread.Start();
}  setup(key) {//do some processing}

Comment: is there any other way to execute
 setup(1);
setup(2);
setup(3);
setup(4);
setup(5);
in 5 different forms concurrently??

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture a local copy of `key` within the `for` loop otherwise by the time the threads actually call `Setup` the value of `key` has become `5`. If you capture a local copy then that value doesn't change and all works as expected.

```
for (long key = 0; key < 5; key++)
{
    var localKey = key;
    var processingThread = new Thread(() => Setup(localKey));
    processingThread.Start();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the `Parallel.ForEach()` and `Parallel.For()` methods.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

Explicitly creating a new thread has large overhead and should be avoided. Only do it if have good reason and already have considered using a thread pool based solution (such as PTL, or similar).

Answer (score -1):

```
for (long key = 0; key < 5; key++)
{
    var processingThread = new Thread(Setup);
    processingThread.Start(key);
}
```

`Setup` parameter type must be changed to `object` (and casted, if needed)

Comment: Setup is actually a method, which is accepting the loop variable as argument.

Comment: Of course. It's signature probably is "void Setup(long key)", isn't it? It need to be changed in "void Setup(object key)".

Comment: how can i start the thread once, make it loop, and do Thread.sleep(500) with each iteration?

Comment: I think you'd better ask another question (and mark this one as answered if your original problem was solved)

Answer (score -2):

If `Parallel.For()` does not provide the trick you can pass them all a AutoResetEvent. 
Call `Wait()` in all your delegates and then call `Set()` after creating all the threads. 
Please take notice in the fact that the system does

```
// THIS ISN'T TESTED AND IS WRITTEN HERE, SO MIND THE SYNTAX, THIS MIGHT NOT COMPILE !!

 AutoResetEvent handle = new AutoResetEvent(true);

 for (long key = 0; key < 5; key++)
 {
    var processingThread = new Thread(() => 
        {
           handle.Wait(); 
           Setup(key)
        } );
    processingThread.Start();
 }

 handle.Set();
```

Comment: I Wrote this on my smart phone and not in Visual Studio. I mentioned this in the answer. the general idea works. I gave it as an alternative to Parallel.For 

If some one marks down. please stat he reason..