Writing repeating parallel loops for animation, avoiding System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For
I am writing a plugin to Rhino which animates some ray-traced data. Rhino handles all the drawing; I just have to provide it with something to draw.
The following Animate function is called from the UI thread using Task.Run(() => Animate(doc, cts.Token, Embree);. Within the function is a while loop which repeats until the CancellationToken is thrown or lengthtraveled > maxTimeLength (both set by the UI thread). The while loop computes each frame of the animation; i.e. the step of the individual points along their path. When a boundary is reached, Embree computes the intersection of that approaching ray with the boundary and determines the direction and length of the reflected ray.
I would like to take advantage of the multi-core processor sitting in front of me and farm out the main for (int i = 0; i < sphereNum; i++) loop (marked below) into multiple concurrent threads.
Currently I am achieving about 45Hz refresh rate on the single thread, but it would be nice if it was more performant for less capable (but still multi-cored) machines.
My impression of Parallel.For(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, Action<int> body) is that it introduces a fair amount of overhead and would be spinning up a new set of threads each time its called - which seems wasteful since I know that the same procedure will simply be repeated ad nauseam. So why not load several threads which each compute a portion of the points (25,000+) and then waits for the data to be drawn, following which command will be given to compute the next animation step.
Here's the Animate function:
private void Animate(RhinoDoc doc, CancellationToken cts, EMBContainer Embree)
{
    double refreshInterval = 1.0 / 45.0;
    int refreshMS = (int)(refreshInterval * 1000.0);
    double slowdownFactor = 1.0 / 20.0;
    double Speed = 10.0;
    double spherestep = refreshInterval * slowdownFactor * Speed;
    double lengthtraveled = 0.0;

    int sphereNum = 25000;
    spheres = new RaySphereData[sphereNum];
    points = new Rhino.Geometry.PointCloud(Enumerable.Repeat(StartPoint, sphereNum));
    int refreshcounter = 1, resettozero = 0;
    long waited = 0;

    System.Numerics.Vector3 start, direction;

    var vectors = StartingVectors();
    start = StartPoint.;
    for (int i = 0; i < sphereNum; i++)
    {
        direction  = vectors[i];
        Embree.RTCRayHit hits = Embree.Intersect(start, direction);

        points[i].Location = StartPoint;
        spheres[i].step = direction; 
        spheres[i].step *= spherestep;
        spheres[i].pathlength = hits.Ray.tfar;
        spheres[i].done = false;

        hits.Hit.Normalize();
        spheres[i].nextdirection = Vector3.Reflect(direction, hits.Hit.normal);
        spheres[i].nextstart = start + direction * hits.Ray.tfar;
    }

    Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
    Stopwatch stopwatch3 = new Stopwatch();
    double interimlength;

    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Stopwatch stopwatch1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    while (true)
    {
        stopwatch2.Start();
        if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) return;

        var delay = Task.Delay(refreshMS); 

        doc.Views.Redraw();
        lengthtraveled += spherestep;
        if (lengthtraveled > maxTimeLength)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
// start multi-threading here; i.e. send Monitor, Barrier or Semaphore signal to the animation frame compute function
            for (int i = 0; i < sphereNum; i++)
            {
                if (lengthtraveled > spheres[i].pathlength)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        interimlength = lengthtraveled - spheres[i].pathlength;
                        direction = spheres[i].nextdirection;
                        start = spheres[i].nextstart;
                        var hits = Embree.Intersect(start, direction);
                        spheres[i].pathlength += hits.Ray.tfar;
                        spheres[i].step = direction.ToVector3d();
                        spheres[i].step.Unitize();
                        points[i].Location = spheres[i].nextstart.ToPoint3d() + (spheres[i].step * interimlength);
                        spheres[i].nextstart = start + direction * hits.Ray.tfar;
                        hits.Hit.Normalize();
                        spheres[i].nextdirection = Vector3.Reflect(direction, hits.Hit.normal);
                    }
                    while (lengthtraveled > spheres[i].pathlength);

                    spheres[i].step *= spherestep;
                }
                else
                {
                    points[i].Location += spheres[i].step;
                }
            }
// end multi-threading
        }
        stopwatch3.Start();
        await delay;
        stopwatch3.Stop();
        stopwatch2.Stop();
        waited += stopwatch3.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        stopwatch3.Reset();
        stopwatch2.Reset();
        if(refreshcounter % 100 == 0)
        {
            stopwatch1.Stop();
            refreshInterval = (stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds - waited) / (1000.0 * refreshcounter);
            refreshMS = (int)(refreshInterval * 1000.0);
            spherestep = refreshInterval * slowdownFactor * Speed;
            for (int i = 0; i < sphereNum; i++)
            {
                spheres[i].step.Unitize();
                spheres[i].step *= spherestep;
            }
            stopwatch1.Start();
        }
        refreshcounter++;
    }
}

private struct RaySphereData
{
    public double pathlength;
    public Rhino.Geometry.Vector3d step;
    public System.Numerics.Vector3 nextstart;
    public System.Numerics.Vector3 nextdirection;
}


I have looked into Barrier, Monitor, and SemaphoreSlim, but either through my lack of understanding or the thinness of the documentation of those .NET features I haven't been able to make it work. Are there any suggestions? (Also if there's any better suggestions for the adaptation of the refresh rate, I'm all for it.)

Your impression may be wrong? Parallel.Foruses (and re-uses) threads from the threadpool. In some cases it can be useful to  limit the number of threads using the MaxDegreeOfParallelism property of a ParallelOptions parameter.
Since this would be much easier than the alternatives you propose, why don't you give it a try (and perhaps benchmark to tweak the MaxDegreeOfParallelismvalue)?

A usefull read (check all the answers!): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405938/save-time-with-parallel-for-loop

The impression isn't completely wrong, only 99.99% so. Starting and scheduling 25K threads has a huge overhead. You can't run more threads at a time than there are cores. Parallel.For by default uses as many worker tasks as there are cores, or more precisely the number returned by Environment.ProcessorCount. That gives the impression of blocking. PFOR partitions the data and uses one worker tasks to process each partition. It doesn't create new threads every time, it uses the current thread and reusable threads for the threadpool for the worker tasks.

Parallel.For/ForEach is made for precisely this type of embarrassingly parallel problem. In fact, Ray Tracing is one of the first examples used to demonstrate Parallel.For, all the way back to 2007

There's a more recent Ray Tracing on WinForms example at .NET Core parallel animated ray-traced bouncing ball but the actual Raytracing loop remains the same - PFOR on the columns, to take advantage of data locality

Rhino uses .NET 8, which is a .NET Core version. Why are you using the .NET Framework 4.8 tag?

Only Rhino8 uses .NET 8; Rhino 6, 7, and 8 all use .NET Framework 4.8. McNeel recommends targeting .NET Framework 4.8 in general for broader compatibility.

That doesn't change how Parallel.For works, but it does mean you're losing a lot of improvements in SIMD and numerics in general. Have you checked the Raytracing example and check the effect of DOP? Have you tried parallelizing per line? If you went from 45 for sequential to just 60 for parallel, you got terrible performance. That's just 30% improvement on a machine that probably has at least 2 cores, on a problem that should result in at least 2x speedup from parallelization . On a quad, 30% is just terrible. That means that whatever you tried has a huge synchronization overhead

@NoseHornScribe I downloaded the Raytracing sample and the improvement was at least 400% on my 6-core machine. From 1.4 FPS for sequential rendering to 5.6 FPS for full parallelism.

@Panagiotis The 45Hz to 60Hz improvement includes the substantial (but still very efficient) overhead which Rhino imposes for its screen drawing routines, as in the line doc.Views.Redraw(); Some day I'll move up to Rhino8 and see if I get some performance improvement from the updated .NET version. I don't know for sure if RhinoCommon uses SIMD behind the scenes for the various vector math functions, but a quick benchmark I did once hinted that it does.


My impression of Parallel.For is that it introduces a fair amount of overhead and would be spinning up a new set of threads each time its called.

Your impression is wrong. By default the Parallel.For method uses the current thread, plus threads from the ThreadPool. You can change the default by providing a custom TaskScheduler, but there is no reason to do that. What I would advise you to do is to specify the MaxDegreeOfParallelism, so that the parallel loop doesn't saturate the ThreadPool:
ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};

Parallel.For(0, 25000, parallelOptions, i =>
{
    // ...
});

In case your application makes heavy use of the ThreadPool, you could consider increasing the threshold for immediate thread creation by using the ThreadPool.SetMinThreads API.

So why not load several threads which each compute a portion of the points [...]?

Because it's unlikely that your custom approach will be better than the tools provided by the .NET standard libraries. Most likely it will be worse, regarding either performance, behavior or correctness, or all of the above.

Thank you. A good and clear explanation of the system. Using Parallel.For I could increase from about 45Hz to 60Hz.

The impression is incorrect. In the .NET Raytracing sample parallelism results in 300% better performance compared to to sequential rendering.
Parallel.For was built to reduce, if not eliminate overhead. In parallel processing, the maximum performance improvement you can achieve is constrained by the non-parallelizable part of the code. The higher the need to synchronize, the lower the performance you can gain.
In a similar question, Parallel vs Serial results aren't understandable, correct usage of Parallel.For in matrix multiplication, and taking care of data locality, resulted in 9 times improvement on a 6 core, hyperthreaded machine, without using SIMD operations. That extra 50% is what one would expect from hyperthreading.
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.22621
Intel Core i7-10850H CPU 2.70GHz, 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.302
  [Host]     : .NET 6.0.7 (6.0.722.32202), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 6.0.7 (6.0.722.32202), X64 RyuJIT


           Method |      Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Ratio |
----------------- |----------:|---------:|---------:|------:|
       SerialMult | 288.63 ms | 5.736 ms | 8.585 ms |  1.00 |
     ParallelMult |  75.92 ms | 1.311 ms | 1.162 ms |  0.26 |
 ParallelMultTemp |  49.63 ms | 0.873 ms | 0.817 ms |  0.17 |
 ParallelMultVect |  33.04 ms | 0.588 ms | 0.521 ms |  0.11 |


Parallel.For Raytracing
Parallel.For is perfectly suited for embarrassingly parallel problems like ray tracing, where the calculations for each pixel aren't affected by the calculations for other pixels. In fact,  Ray tracing is one of first Parallel.For examples, going back all the way to an MSDN Magazine article from 2007. A similar example for WinForms on .NET Core (which includes .NET 5 and later) can be found in the .NET Samples repo:  .NET Core parallel animated ray-traced bouncing ball
In the example, the parallel rendering method is simple :
internal void RenderParallel(Scene scene, int[] rgb, ParallelOptions options)
{
    try
    {
        Parallel.For(0, _screenHeight, options, y =>
        {
            int stride = y * _screenWidth;
            Camera camera = scene.Camera;
            for (int x = 0; x < _screenWidth; x++)
            {
                Color color = TraceRay(new Ray(camera.Pos, GetPoint(x, y, camera)), scene, 0);
                rgb[x + stride] = color.ToInt32();
            }
        });
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
                // Catch this to prevent the UI from crashing, we know a cancellation will occur.
    }
}

The performance improvement was over 300% - from around 5 FPS for sequential processing, to at least 15 FPS for full parallelism.
Data locality
In essence, this code processes separate lines, not separate points in parallel. Parallel.For works by partitioning the data in as many partitions as there are cores and using one worker task for each partition. This reduces the need for synchronization between threads to a minimum. By parallelizing along lines, the code increases the cache of cache hits, as points in a line have a higher chance of being loaded together in the CPU cache.
In the benchmark above, using a local temporary copy improved performance from 3x to almost 6x. Using a local row copy produced the final 9x improvement.
In other words, using Parallel.For(0, 25000 is a bad idea because it prevents partitioning and results in the worst caching behavior and can't calculate more points than the number of cores at the same time. At least it won't create more threads than cores.
Parallel.For execution
The worker tasks aren't executed in new threads. They run on reusable threads that come from a threadpool. Parallel.For uses the current thread as well, which gives the impression of blocking. To avoid blocking the UI, the sample's render loop runs in a background task :
Task.Factory.StartNew(RenderLoop,_cancellation.Token, _cancellation.Token) 
...

By default Parallel.For uses as many workers as there are cores or more precisely, it uses Environment.ProcessorCount to set the initial MaxDegreeOfParallelism. On a 8-core machine, that's 8. On a 8-core with Hyperthreading, that's 16.
You can change the number or workers by changing the ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism property. In the sample, the initial value is equal to the default, the number of cores:
private int _degreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;

What about 25K threads?
Starting 25K threads on the other hand leads to a huge overhead as all those threads strive to get scheduled on the same cores, causing their stacks to get loaded and unloaded every time. The default stack size in .NET is 4MB, so 25K threads will result in a lot of data getting loaded and unloaded just to run the thread. All that, just to run 8 threads at a time.
Worse, there's no specific order in how threads are scheduled, which means processing points is essentially random, increasing the chance of cache misses.
